# How to arrange button of equal sizes of the phone width?

Tags: android, xml, layout

I am trying to arrange 4 buttons of equal sizes of the phone width in XML. I tried to use with relative layout with their relationship and width of buttons as "wrap_content". But the problem i faced with RelativeLayout is circular relationship is not allowed.

[image: I need the icons to be placed like this in layout]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `android:layout_weight` to make your button equal and fit them according to the width of the device screen. You can apply `android:layout_weight="1"` to all 4 buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Use `LinearLayout` with `android:weightSum="1.0"` and assign `android:layout_weight = "0.25"` to each of your 4 button(`weight_sum/no of buttons`).

Answer (score 0):

Under the Relative Layout you mention a Linear Layout whose
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight_sum="4"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_weight="1"  for all buttons and their parent layout

it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I think my answere also will be helpful though this is not directly related to above question.
I wanted to arrange 2 icons in the footer area of the application. here is what I did.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Description"
        android:onClick="onClickBtn"
        android:layout_margin="35dp"
        android:src="@drawable/backbut" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".5"
         android:layout_margin="35dp"
        android:background="@drawable/copy"
        android:contentDescription="@string/Description"
        android:onClick="onClickBtn" />
</LinearLayout>
```

since i wanted to give same width I have set android:layout_weight=".5" and I wanted to have a margin amoung two icons. therfore I set android:layout_margin="35dp".